# GANEstimator with l1_pixel_loss (pix2pix)

Tags: tensorflow

The recently released [TFGAN module README](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/gan) has information on how to combine `l1_pixel_loss`:

```py
# Modify the loss tuple to include the pixel loss.
gan_loss = tfgan.losses.combine_adversarial_loss(
    gan_loss, gan_model, l1_pixel_loss, weight_factor=FLAGS.weight_factor)
```

The module also includes a GANEstimator class, but there aren't many examples and specificaly there is no example on how to combine the `l1_pixel_loss` in it.

```py
# Create GAN estimator.
gan_estimator = estimator.GANEstimator(
    model_dir,
    generator_fn=generator_fn,
    discriminator_fn=discriminator_fn,
    generator_loss_fn=tfgan.losses.wasserstein_generator_loss,
    discriminator_loss_fn=tfgan.losses.wasserstein_discriminator_loss,
    generator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizier(0.1, 0.5),
    discriminator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizier(0.1, 0.5))
```

How can I properly add the `l1_pixel_loss` to the GANEstimator?

Comment: is there any progress? by the way, how to get discriminator loss and generator loss separately?